# Why cant i add the value in this variable to my table?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to add a variable (key) to a string(table_data) and use it in the creation of a table, my problem is that when I try to concatenate it into a string it gives me the variable name and not the value. when I print the variable on its own I get the value. when I try open the page with this table I get the error "Could not parse the remainder: '\'webapp-graphv2\' '+key+' from '\'webapp-graphv2\' '+key+'". I'm really struggling to figure this out and would appreciate some help.

```
function populateTable(){
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    $("#stats tr").remove();
    var table_data ='';


    for (var key in data){
      table_data += '<td><a href = "{% url \'webapp-graphv2\' '+key+'%}">Link</a></td>';
      table_data += '<td>' +key+ '</td>'
      table_data += '<td>' +data[key].EUR.PRICE+ '</td>';
      table_data += '<td>' +data[key].EUR.HIGHDAY+ '</td>';
      table_data += '<td>' +data[key].EUR.LOWDAY+ '</td>';
      table_data += '<td>' +data[key].EUR.MKTCAP+ '</td>';

      if (data[key].EUR.CHANGEPCT24HOUR[0] == '-') {
        table_data += '<td style = "color:red">' +data[key].EUR.CHANGEPCT24HOUR+ '</td>';
      } else {
        table_data += '<td style = "color:green">' +data[key].EUR.CHANGEPCT24HOUR+ '</td>';
      }
      table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#stats').append(table_data);
    },
  })
  setTimeout(populateTable,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write as below

```
table_data += "<td><a href = '{% url\\webapp-graphv2\\" + key + "%}'>Link</a</td>";
```